# How to group the Similar value array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logic

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] arr3 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] arr4 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] arr5 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] arr6 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        Order Order1 = new Order { OrderId = 1, Deatils = arr1 };
        Order Order2 = new Order { OrderId = 2, Deatils = arr2 };
        Order Order3 = new Order { OrderId = 3, Deatils = arr3 };
        Order Order4 = new Order { OrderId = 4, Deatils = arr4 };
        Order Order5 = new Order { OrderId = 5, Deatils = arr5 };
        Order Order6 = new Order { OrderId = 6, Deatils = arr6 };

        // I want to Output like this based on same values in details object.
        string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_1 = "1,4,5";
        string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_2 = "2,3";
        string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_3 = "5";

    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int[] Deatils { get; set; }

}
```

I want to output like this because OrderId-1,4,5 have the same values in Details.

string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_1 = "1,4,5";

string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_2 = "2,3";

string similarOrderDetailsOrderIds_3 = "5";

Comment: By "similar" do you mean "contains the same values"? Does the order of the values matter?

Comment: yes 'similar' means contains the same values but order is not matter

Comment: @stuartd yes 'similar' means contains the same values but order is not matter.

Comment: Are they always int, how many do you need to compare, 10, 10,000, 1Million 1Billion?

Comment: @DekuDesu actually the real object is different for simplicity I have just created these int array.

Comment: So the real `T` is a complex runtime type such as a user-defined class or struct?

Comment: DekuDesu correct.

Comment: Make sure to include that in the original question, also have you already implemented something that can do this/or perhaps isn't working as intended?

Comment: You can do this with EqualityComparer see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118089/hashing-an-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension method is a generic generalization of the solution provided by Michael Liu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123103/2025062) which orders elements prior to hash code generation and will work for any T which itself correctly implements `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int GetCollectionHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        return ((IStructuralEquatable)e.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray())
            .GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }
}
```

You can utilize it like so:

```
var orders = new[] { Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4, Order5, Order6 };

var groups = orders
    .Where(x => x.Deatils != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Deatils.GetCollectionHashCode())
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.OrderId));
```

Note: *Deatils* typo above is intentional as per OP.

Comment: Thanks @Creyke for your answer. it look like depends on element order also, suppose if I change the order for  arr3 = { 1, 3, 2 }; elements like this then result set is different

Comment: Element order is handled by `e.OrderByDescending(x => x)` so all enumerables are ordered prior to hashing.

Comment: Hi @Creyke how to handle the null value in this query suppose int[] arr6 = null; then it throws error how to handle this

Comment: Use a `Where()` method. Have updated answer to reflect. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ as the other answer provided or create a helper method to group them for you.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Aggregate<T>(IEnumerable<T> ungrouped, Func<T, T, bool> Expression)
{
    // create a place to put the result
    List<List<T>> groupedItems = new();

    // create a mutable storage to keep track which ones we shouldn't compare 
    List<T> mutableBag = ungrouped.ToArray().ToList();

    // n^2 isn't great but it was easy to implement, consider creating a hash from all elements and use those instead of manual comparisons
    foreach (var left in ungrouped)
    {
        // create a place to store any similar items
        List<T> similarItems = new();

        // compare element to every remaining element, if they are similar add the other to the similar list
        foreach (var right in mutableBag)
        {
            if (Expression(left, right))
            {
                similarItems.Add(right);
            }
        }

        // if we didn't find any similar items continue and let GC collect similar items
        if (similarItems.Count == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // since we found items remove the from the mutable bag so we don't have duplicate entries
        foreach (var item in similarItems)
        {
            mutableBag.Remove(item);
        }

        // add the similar items to the result
        groupedItems.Add(similarItems);
    }

    return groupedItems;
}
public static bool Compare<T>(T[] Left, T[] Right)
{
    // this compare method could be anything I would advise against doing member comparison like this, this is simplified to provide how to use the Aggregate method and what the CompareMethod might look like for comlpex types
    if (Left.Length != Right.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (var item in Left)
    {
        if (Right.Contains(item) is false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the given example

```cs
Order Order1 = new Order { OrderId = 1, Deatils = arr1 };
Order Order2 = new Order { OrderId = 2, Deatils = arr2 };
Order Order3 = new Order { OrderId = 3, Deatils = arr3 };
Order Order4 = new Order { OrderId = 4, Deatils = arr4 };
Order Order5 = new Order { OrderId = 5, Deatils = arr5 };
Order Order6 = new Order { OrderId = 6, Deatils = arr6 };

Order[] arrs = { Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4, Order5, Order6 };
```

We could use this new helper method like this:

```cs
var groupedItems = Aggregate(arrs, (left, right) => Compare(left.Deatils, right.Deatils));
```