# C#: Compare two ArrayList of custom class and find duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, arraylist, duplicates

I have two arrays of ArrayList.

```
public class ProductDetails
{
    public string id;
    public string description;
    public float rate;
}

ArrayList products1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList products2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList duplicateProducts = new ArrayList();
```

Now what I want is to get all the products (with all the fields of ProductDetails class) having duplicate description in both `products1` and `products2`.

I can run two for/while loops as traditional way, but that would be very slow specially if I will be having over 10k elements in **both arrays**.

So probably something can be done with LINQ.

Comment: Use `List<T>`, not `ArrayList`.

Comment: You should probably use a database.

Comment: I agree with @SLaks it would be much easier to do this using a SubQuery with the outter Select being `Select Distinct` and the `Inner Select doing your Group By Having Count(*) >= 2`

Comment: A "textbook" implementation is to sort both sequences (`O(n lg n)` if needing a comparison ordering) and then walk the sequences together. This is one of the several algorithms used by databases.

Comment: @user2864740: You mean `O(n lg n)`.  Or make a dictionary and do it in `O(n)`.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I just noticed/corrected the goof :} The intent of the comment was to stay within the realm of 'loops'.

Comment: I am already using SQLite. One list is in database and one list I have imported from Excel Spreadsheet. I am pretty new to programming, so just not getting it how to do it in a effective and quick way. @MethodMan can u pls guide me more with giving some example of the query.

Comment: I know I can use where clause in SQL query but how to do it if I am having so many multiple values for the where clause which is in the second array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use linQ, you need write your own EqualityComparer where you override both methods *Equals* and *GetHashCode()*

```
 public class ProductDetails
    { 
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string description {get; set;}
        public float rate {get; set;}
    }

public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductDetails>
{

    public bool Equals(ProductDetails x, ProductDetails y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return x != null && y != null && x.id.Equals(y.id) && x.description.Equals(y.description);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductDetails obj)
    {
        //Get hash code for the description field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductDesc = obj.description == null ? 0 : obj.description.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the idfield. 
        int hashProductId = obj.id.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductDesc ^ hashProductId ;
    }
}
```

Now, supposing you have this objects:

```
ProductDetails [] items1= { new ProductDetails { description= "aa", id= 9, rating=2.0f }, 
                       new ProductDetails { description= "b", id= 4, rating=2.0f} };

ProductDetails [] items= { new ProductDetails { description= "aa", id= 9, rating=1.0f }, 
                       new ProductDetails { description= "c", id= 12, rating=2.0f } };


IEnumerable<ProductDetails> duplicates =
    items1.Intersect(items2, new ProductComparer());
```

Comment: Thanks for the so well commented code. I will surely try this code but truly speaking I am not getting about the `GetHashCode` stuff. What if I have couple of more fields in my custom class? Do I need to `^` it with same pattern? Like `hasProductDesc ^ hasProductId ^ hasProductRate ^ hasProductMake`? Also what if I only want to compare these two different objects/arraylist based on description, means other fields can be different.

Comment: Hi, If you have multiples properties I wouldn't do it because if you XOR many properties eventually they might converge to 0 causing lots of collisions. Hence, destroying the Equals method. Read this for further information. [GetHashCode override of object containing generic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638761/gethashcode-override-of-object-containing-generic-array/639098#639098)

Comment: In the code above, I assumed that the equality is defined by the id and description. If it is only by the description you can remove this `x.id.Equals(y.id) ` and this `^ hashProductId` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider overriding the *System.Object.Equals* method.

```
   public class ProductDetails
   {
     public string id;
     public string description;
     public float rate;

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
       if(obj is ProductDetails == null)
          return false;

      if(ReferenceEquals(obj,this))
          return true;

       ProductDetails p = (ProductDetails)obj;
       return description == p.description;
    }
  }
```

Filtering would then be as simple as:

```
var result = products1.Where(product=>products2.Contains(product));
```

EDIT:

Do consider that this implementation is not optimal..

Moreover- it has been proposed in the comments to your question that you use a data base.
This way performance will be optimized - as per the database implementation
 In any case- the overhead will not be yours.

However, you can optimize this code by using a Dictionary or a HashSet:
Overload the *System.Object.GetHashCode* method:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return description.GetHashCode();
}
```

You can now do this:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<ProductDetails>(products1);
var result = products2.Where(product=>hashSet.Contains(product));
```

Which will boost your performance to an extent since lookup will be less costly.

Comment: You must also override `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: That's `O(n^2)`.  Use a dictionary.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, lazy at this hour. will add shortly.

Answer (score 0):

10k elements is nothing, however make sure you use proper collection types. `ArrayList` is long deprecated, use `List<ProductDetails>`.

Next step is implementing proper `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides for your class. The assumption here is that `description` is the key since that's what you care about from a duplication point of view:

```
public class ProductDetails
{
    public string id;
    public string description;
    public float rate;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p = obj as ProductDetails;
        return ReferenceEquals(p, null) ? false : description == obj.description;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => description.GetHashCode();    
}
```

Now we have options. One easy and efficient way of doing this is using a hash set:

```
var set = new HashSet<ProductDetails>();
var products1 = new List<ProductDetails>();  // fill it
var products2 = new List<ProductDetails>();  // fill it

// shove everything in the first list in the set
foreach(var item in products1)
    set.Add(item);

// and simply test the elements in the second set
foreach(var item in products2)
    if(set.Contains(item))
    {
        // item.description was already used in products1, handle it here
    }
```

This gives you linear (`O(n)`) time-complexity, best you can get.