# Vb.net / C# - sort list/array starting from a mid point

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, sorting, sql-order-by

Is there an easy way to sort a list starting at a particular value?

A B C D E F

So we can start from a passed in value say 'C'

C D E F A B

I want optimise a time slot list and it will be best to sort the order from a starting time so it doesn't need to iterate all times it doesn't need to.

Comment: Please elaborate. The example you have given is already sorted and it looks more like reordering of elements?!

Comment: Sorry about that. I can order using anonymous function ok as most do for simple sorting. so list becomes sorted already but would like a custom starting point for the order to start.

Comment: Implement your own mergesort algorithm and send the range you want to sort.

Comment: Further to this. I'm defining a list of time slots , 08:00, 10:00, 17:00, 19:00, 22:00 etc.  I'm checking every minute of a time frame to find which slot each minute fits. A lot of minutes through the day so just trying to optimise a little of there are a lot of timeslots. It's not too bad for 1-3. My current code stops checking when each minute is assigned.

Comment: You should just edit your question to add the details you are explaining in the comments to the question itself to make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: I was trying to keep it as simple as possible and understandable. I've done a bad job. Currently on the phone so will amend when I'm back at a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
ArrayList.Sort(int index, int count, IEqualityComparer comparer)
```

This method sorts the elements in a range of elements in ArrayList using the specified comparer.

> **Parameters**
>
> **index**
>
> Type: System.Int32 The zero-based starting index of the range to sort.
>
> **count**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The length of the range to sort.
>
> **comparer**
>
> Type: System.Collections.IComparer The IComparer implementation to use
>   when comparing elements.
>
> -or-
>
> A null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) to use the IComparable
>   implementation of each element.

There is an example right here explaining how to use it.

[ArrayList.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6th6159(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you don't know how to implement the Equality comparer you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457194/c-compare-two-arraylist-of-custom-class-and-find-duplicates/39457495#39457495) too

**Update:**

From your array: `A B C D E F`

Let's suppose that it is in this object and it is instantiated:

```
List<string> array;
```

So you can do this:

```
public List<string> foo(List<string> array, int i) { 
  array.Sort(i, array.size() - i, null);
  List<string> aux = array.Skip(i).Take(array.Size() - i );
  aux.AddRange(array.Take(i));
  return aux;
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
List<string myNewArray = foo(array, 2);
```

Comment: But does that just leave first part of the list unsorted anywhere above the starting index?

Comment: yes, it will sort starting from index, n elements. Where n is the count parameter.

Comment: But I want the closest match to be end up at index 0 then everything else in order from there then cycle round. B, C, F, A, D,E to become 'C', D, E, F, A, B

Comment: Split into two parts, sort both separately and append the second part to the first.

Comment: That splitting did cross my mind as an option. I thought it was a little manual and was hoping for some clever .net function I hadn't come across.

Comment: Thanks Roberto Think that's pretty much done it,  I made a few amends.#

Comment: Thanks Roberto Think that's pretty much done it,  I made a few amends.<!-- language: vb -->
 Public Function foo(_array As List(Of String), i As String) As List(Of String)
        _array.Sort()
        Dim foundIndex As Integer = _array.FindIndex(Function(x) x > "C")
        Dim aux As List(Of String) = _array.Skip(foundIndex).Take(_array.Count - foundIndex).ToList
        aux.AddRange(_array.Take(foundIndex))
        Return aux
    End Function

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] z = new char[] { 'B', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'D', 'E' };
        Array.Sort(z);

        char[] x,y;
        Split<char>(z, 2, out x, out y);

        char[] combined = y.Concat(x).ToArray ();
    }
    public static void Split<T>(T[] array, int index, out T[] first, out T[] second)
    {
        first = array.Take(index).ToArray();
        second = array.Skip(index).ToArray();
    }
```